# How to pass a db object and model object to function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linqkit

I want to turn this into a function. I will be passing the db object and the MVC model object.
Here is the original code:

```
var SomethingApproval = db.Somethings.AsQueryable();
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Something>();
predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Approved == "N");
SomethingApproval = SomethingApproval.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
```

I want a function like this

```
Function ApprovedItems (dbObject, modelObject)
{

var SomethingApproval = dbobject.AsQueryable();
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<modelObject>();
predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Approved == "N");
SomethingApproval = SomethingApproval.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
return SomethingApproval
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going out on a limb here... think its a generics question

```
public IQueryable<T> ApprovedItems<T>(DbObject db)
    where T : IApprovable
{
    var query = db.Set<T>();
    return query.Where(p => p.Approved == "N");
}

public interface IApprovable
{
    //By the way I do not Approve of an 
    //approve flag with type of string
    string Approved {get;}
}
```